# Capturing de selected checkbox in multi select dataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

So I have some old code I need to enhance and was hoping for some help.

I have this dataGrid:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgSharedUserList" Runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
DataKeyField="user_id" Width="98%" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="LightSteelBlue">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" Font-Bold="True" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid"></HeaderStyle>
<ItemStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid"></ItemStyle>
<Columns>
<mbrsc:RowSelectorColumn SelectionMode="Multiple" OnSelectionChanged="saveSharedUserReferrals" AutoPostBack="true"></mbrsc:RowSelectorColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="User_Id" HeaderText="User_Id" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="FullName" HeaderText="User Name" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="loginId" HeaderText="User Login" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Email" HeaderText="E-mail" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
</Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

I can populate the Grid no issues.  I am able to successfully capture the row click event, and have the following code for handling that:

```
protected void saveSharedUserReferrals(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
RowSelectorColumn rsc = RowSelectorColumn.FindColumn(dgSharedUserList);
int selIndex = 0;
if (rsc.SelectedIndexes.Length == 0)
{
// How do I get the index of the row de selected??
}
else
{
selIndex = rsc.SelectedIndexes[0];
string user_id = dgSharedUserList.DataKeys[selIndex].ToString();
}
}
```

My issue is I need to get the Key of the un selected row so that I can un select the row in the database too.  What am I missing?  I have tried to capture it in the event and in the RowSelectorColumn object to no avail.

Please note I would like to keep the checkbox if at all possible so the users can visualize what has and hasn't been selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use a checkbox instead of mbrsc:RowSelectorColumn:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgSharedUserList" Runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
DataKeyField="user_id" Width="98%" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="LightSteelBlue">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" Font-Bold="True" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid"></HeaderStyle>
<ItemStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid"></ItemStyle>
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateColumn>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox runat="server" UserIdFld='<%# Eval("user_id") %>' ID="RowLevelCheckBox" OnCheckedChanged="saveSharedUserReferrals" AutoPostBack="true"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateColumn>
<%--<mbrsc:RowSelectorColumn SelectionMode="Multiple" OnSelectionChanged="saveSharedUserReferrals" AutoPostBack="true"></mbrsc:RowSelectorColumn>--%>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="User_Id" HeaderText="User_Id" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="10%" />
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="FullName" HeaderText="User Name" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="loginId" HeaderText="User Login" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Email" HeaderText="E-mail" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
</Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

And in the server:

```
 protected void saveSharedUserReferrals(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var id = ((CheckBox)sender).Attributes["UserIdFld"].ToString();
            //RowSelectorColumn rsc = RowSelectorColumn.FindColumn(dgSharedUserList);
            //int selIndex = 0;
            //if (rsc.SelectedIndexes.Length == 0)
            //{
            //    // How do I get the index of the row de selected??
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    selIndex = rsc.SelectedIndexes[0];
            //    string user_id = dgSharedUserList.DataKeys[selIndex].ToString();
            //}
        }
```

Comment: Ok, this is super close.  The only thing left would be to know how if the checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: You can do var checked= (CheckBox)sender).checked i think

Comment: Yeah, I just got that one figured out.  Thanks  bunch.

Comment: I tried to provide the details needed for the question.  Was the question ok?

Comment: Sure, the question was ok, and detailed.

Comment: Thanks again for the assist amigo!